# mysqli_fetch_array and if-else condition for validation

Tags: php, mysqli

Something is wrong with my php,

I'm doing an account validation where if the data exist it will display "There is data" and else "No data"...

When I enter the first 'row' reference_id and submit, it shows "There is data" which is correct but when I entered the second to the last 'row' reference_id it shows "No data" even though it exist in my Database!

Database:

```
reference_id (varchar 250)
status (varchar250)
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_valid'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['reference_id'])) 
    {

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client_record");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

            if ($result['reference_id'] == $_POST['reference_id'])
            {
               echo"<script type='text/javascript'> alert('There is data'); window.location.href='next_page.php';  </script>";         
            }

            if ($result['reference_id'] !== $_POST['reference_id']) {
                echo"<script type='text/javascript'> alert('No data.'); window.location.href='this_page.php';  </script>";
            }
    } 
}
```

I am not sure if it's the `mysqli_fetch_array` fault or the if-else condition is wrong?

if you guys know the problem please help me?

Comment: Make use of prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: `var_dump($result['reference_id'], $_POST['reference_id']);`  are both values what you expect them to be? You can also use `mysqli_error($con);` to get any MySQL errors. And as a final note, one of your comparison is strict, while the other is not.

Comment: @Qirel it probably is the comparison issue.

Comment: @Script47, as the code stands there is no risk of SQL injection, and nothing to prepare for a prepared statement! although the correct answer probably should :)

Comment: And don't need to compare the values just put where clause in query and check the result if result is empty it means `no data`.

Comment: use a WHERE clause in your SQL to do this much more efficiently and quickly instead of pulling back all the rows and comparing them one-by-one.

Comment: Also, don't make two different `if` for checking a condition and the opposite, just use `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query execution currently only looks at the first row. A `fetch` needs to be looped to iterate over all rows. e.g.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client_record");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

should be

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client_record");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

but this is inefficient. When looking for a specific record use a `where` clause. Parameterized queries also will prevent SQL injections, and quoting issues. The `i` in the `bind_param` is for an integer, if your id is a string use `s`.

```
$prepared = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM client_record where reference_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prepared, 'i', $_POST['reference_id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($prepared);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($prepared);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($prepared)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client_record");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

This will give you the first row from the table.

Add a `WHERE reference_id = :refid` clause?!

Then bind the refid parameter, so as to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: `mysqli_*` supports named placeholders?

Comment: @Script47 I don't think so

Comment: `mysqli_` does *not* support named placeholders.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yep, I know it was more of a rhetorical nudge to the OP which went ***whoosh***.

Comment: @shanechiu care to provide a source?

Comment: @shanechiu `?` are question mark placeholders, not named placeholders. Please reread the link you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Lapiz, the problem is actually with the comparison operator:

```
($result['reference_id'] == $_POST['reference_id'])
```

This will check the first reference_id from the returned set in array.

The best way to tackle this would be to use `if (in_array(5, $result))` where 5 is the needle and $result is the array haystack.

Because all you are doing is to check if the reference exists in the returned data set .

This is also good design practices, to collect results and avoid multiple reference queries each time, hit the database once and query the result set.

If its a multidemnsional array loop through the set:

```
foreach($result as $resultItem)
{
    if(in_array("reference_id", $resultItem, true))
    {
        echo "There is Data";
    }
}
```

Good Luck .

Comment: I think `in_array` works with single dimensional array.

Comment: `$result` will never have the record the OP wants with the current code.

Comment: The if condition will just check the `key` in result if key with what ever value is exist it will return true. But the user want to match with the value which is passed in $_POST array.